# Angular - dynamically disable input with getter on Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following control on my Angular reactive form:

```js
name: this.name = this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: this.isNameDisabled }, this.nameValidations )
```

`isNameDisabled` is a getter as following:

```js
private get isNameDisabled(): boolean {
    return this.isDisabled;
}
```

The first load works correctly, but when updating `this.isDisabled` to `True`, disabled property is not updated to true, and the input is still enabled.

Is there any way to dynamically disable the input without using `this.name.disable()`?

Comment: Have you tried by adding disabled property in HTML?

Comment: @VinceCyriac not a good practice in reactive forms

Comment: > Is there any way to dynamically disable the input without using this.name.disable()?

No.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `name: this.name = this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: this.isNameDisabled }, this.nameValidations )`  will work only to initial behavior, if you change the value of `this.isNameDisabled` will no reflect to the control.

To what you need the best approach is `this.form.controls['name'].disable();`

Comment: Without form.controls['name'], just `this.name.disable()` to disable and `this.name.enable()` to enable.

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem with calling this.name.disable() ?

You could use a directive:

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[customDisable]'
})
export class CustomDisableDirective {

  @Input() set customDisable( isDisabled: boolean ) {
    const action = isDisabled ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }

}
```

Then use it inside your HTML:

```
<input [formControl]="formControl" [customDisable]="isNameDisabled()">
```

Comment: You should not call methods from template

Comment: We should not call methods from template because it is called every time Angular change detection runs. It could be an issue if the function is time consuming. Here we are talking about a boolean then it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in template by assigning a variable to a disabled attribute. In that case you'd have a method which sets disabled variable like so:

```
isNameDisabled = false;

ngOnInit(){
  this.setNameDisabled();
}

setNameDisabled() {
  // this is just an example, you should replace it with any logic that you have
  this.isNameDisabled = true;
}
```

And template should look as following:

```
<input [formControl]="formControl" [attr.disabled]="isNameDisabled">
```

Comment: If you use [disabled] attribute and reactive form you will get this warning message: "It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive ...". The CustomDisableDirective above will not rise any warning / error.

Comment: In that case you can use `[attr.disabled]` instead of `[disabled]` to solve the problem. Btw this is the most simple solution, I agree that custom directive might be better option, of course, dependent of use case